# оптимальная функция удаления списка стоп слов в строке

Tags: python

Подскажите эта функция оптимальна для проверки и удаления списка стоп слов в строке или ее можно как-то улучшить? Нужно проверять за раз где-то 1000 строк.

```
def form_valid(query):
    query = query.lower()
    stopwords_name = ('фбу', 'пао', 'оао', 'ип', 'ооо', 'зао', 'ао', '"', '<', '>', "'", '„', '«', '»', ',',
                      'общество с ограниченной ответственностью', 'публичное акционерное общество',
                      'открытое акционерное общество', 'закрытое акционерное общество',
                      'акционерное общество', 'индивидуальный предприниматель')

    for i in stopwords_name:
        query = query.replace(i, '')

    return query.strip()
```

Comment: Регуляркой лучше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import re

def multisub(subs, subject):
    pattern = '|'.join('(%s)' % re.escape(p) for p, s in subs)
    substs  = [s for p, s in subs]
    replace = lambda m: substs[m.lastindex - 1]
    return re.sub(pattern, replace, subject)


text = '''
Было :
stopwords_name = (('фбу', ''), ('пао', ''), ('оао', ''), ('ип', ''), ('ооо', ''), ('зао', ''), ('ао', ''), 
                  1 ооо «ОРРЛА Глобал Групп», оао ип ооо 
                  2 общество с ограниченной ответственностью, ООО — учрежденное одним или несколькими ...
                  ('"', ''), ('<', ''), ('>, '')', ("'", ''), ('„', ''), ('«', ''), ('»', ''), (',', ''),
                      ('общество с ограниченной ответственностью', ''), ('публичное акционерное общество', ''),
                      ('открытое акционерное общество', ('закрытое акционерное общество',
                      ('акционерное общество', ''), ('индивидуальный предприниматель', ''))

Нет, эта функция плоха. Она наудаляет там, где не надо. 
Например, из «заоблачная ипотека» она сделает «блачная отека». Вряд ли вам это требуется.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'''
print(text)

stopwords_name = (('фбу ', ''), ('пао ', ''), ('оао ', ''), ('ип ', ''), 
                  ('ооо ', ''), ('зао ', ''), ('ао ', ''), 
                  ('"', ''), ('<', ''), ('>', ''), ("'", ''), ('„', ''), ('«', ''), ('»', ''), (',', ''),
                  ('общество с ограниченной ответственностью', ''), ('публичное акционерное общество', ''),
                  ('открытое акционерное общество', ''), ('закрытое акционерное общество', ''),
                  ('акционерное общество', ''), ('индивидуальный предприниматель', ''),
                  ('было', 'Стало'))


newText = multisub(stopwords_name, text.lower())
print(newText)
```

Answer (score 2):

Нет, эта функция плоха. Она наудаляет там, где не надо. Например, из «заоблачная ипотека» она сделает «блачная отека». Вряд ли вам это требуется.